# Export list of relevant public Facebook group/pages URLS

Tags: facebook, url, export, facebook-group

I am attempting to export a list of URLS all Facebook groups and pages relevant to a search query.

At present, if I search the term ("parents") in the search bar on Facebook, the drop down list is populated, but I cannot find a way to capture these links, and to do so at a large scale (given that there are thousands of groups/pages which include the term "parents")

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that and should not do that. See also the [Automated Data Collection Terms](https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos_terms.php). It's not allowed by Facebook.